# if then conflicts php

Tags: php, scripting

I want to do a quick `if-then` to echo the `s` if it has more than 1 hour. The variables are already assigned if I were to do it on the next line. Any kind of help I can on this is greatly appreciated.

```
$img3['tdiff'] = $img3['tdiff']." Hour".if($img3['tdiff']>1) 
{ 
    echo "s";
};
```

I pretty much want to add the `s` if it has more than one hour... Please help me if you can, and thank you in advance!

Comment: That's just not valid syntax. Separate the if statement from the variable assignment. It's easier to read anyway.

Comment: I don't want to, is there any other way to do it without separating the variables?

Comment: That's a terrible reason. Seriously.

Comment: $img3['tdiff'].= " Hour". ($img3['tdiff']>1 ? 's' : '');

Comment: @Twisted1919 that works too, glad I posted this - learning something new every day

Comment: that's good, but please keep in mind for future code, do not sacrifice readability just to write less code, it doesn't worth it:)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Ternary Operator: `?:`

```
$img3['tdiff'] = $img3['tdiff'] . " Hour" . ( $img3['tdiff'] > 1 ? "s" : "" );
```

Though in this case you'd want to use a pluralization library.

Comment: That's wonderful! Thank you so much! I never knew that was possible until you... thanks again!

Comment: You can shorten it as [@Twisted1919 proposes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001702/if-then-conflicts-php#comment22818139_16001702) .

Answer (score -1):

```
if($img3['tdiff'] > 1) {
    $s = "s";
} else {
    $s = "";
}
$img3['tdiff'] = $img3['tdiff']. " Hour". $s;
```

Edit: added an else clause to avoid an undefined variable

Comment: and what if $img3['tdiff'] <= 1, wouldn't $s be undefined?

Comment: yes, it would be undefined, but would that really be a problem?

Comment: of course it will be a problem don't you think? Do you want warnings into your page disclosing the path where your files reside?
Think twice, please :)

Comment: aahh... silly me... sorry for that one... I should at least have put in an else clause...